# Create a specific role in a replicated AZURE SQL database, which is in read mode

Tags: azure-sql-database, role

Can you give me some help with my Azure Sql, I am having a difficulty with assigning a new role to a database with "geo-redundancy".

**My current structure is:**

- **BD1** in zone_A replicated to another **BD2** (read only) in zone_B

**Drawback**

- I have a new user with new roles that were not replicated in my BD2, and I want to manually execute my statement without stopping my data replication. Could you help me solve if you had a similar problem?

[image]

Comment: your code suggests it tries ton update bd2

Comment: that's the idea, my BD1 already has the role I need, but my BD2 does not yet.

I thought replication would already do that, but I need to run in production without stopping data replication

Comment: Is the user server level (created in mater) or database level?  if it's server level then make sure the SID is the same on both or the replicated database won't be able to use it.

Comment: I am trying to create the login with the same sid, but in that case it gives me the error 15419, Supplied parameter sid should be binary (16), This is a post where I was consulting on the subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/609681/create-the-same-login-as-on-the-primary-server-usi.html?childToView=611292#answer-611292